Azure app gets unauthorized even when i get token
To start with. I am super new to azure platform. Trying to figure out while i go how to solve this issue.
private class TokenRequestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        RequestBody formBody = new FormBody.Builder()
                .add("client_id", "{CLIENT_ID}")
                .add("client_secret", "{CLIENT_SECRET}")
                .add("scope", "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/.default")
                .add("grant_type", "client_credentials")
                .build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://login.windows.net/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token")
                .post(formBody)
                .build();
        try (Response response = client.newCall(request).execute()) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                String responseBody = response.body().string();
                String responseHeader = response.headers().toString();         
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                String accessToken = jsonObject.getString("access_token");
                SharedPreferences._instance.setToken(accessToken);
                return accessToken;
            } else {
                return "Request failed: " + response.code();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "Request failed: " + e.getMessage();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // Handle the token or error response
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}

This code is for testing purpose and will be changed in the future as soon as we make everything just work.
This token request task is able to retrieve a token. But the problem is when we try to call our custom api. We get 401 and the response lets us know that the credentials is not valid.
The url looks something like
https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/{TENANT_ID}/Production/api/effekt/timeReport/v2.0/companies({COMPANY_ID})
The app we created that corresponds to the CLIENT_ID and CLIENT_SECRET have

With all these permissions it is still getting 401 back. What could be wrong? Is there a way to know what permission that is needed? Or what we need to do
Decoded token
{
  "typ": "JWT",
  "alg": "RS256",
  "x5t": "L1KfKFI_jnXbwWc22xZxw1sUHH0",
  "kid": "L1KfKFI_jnXbwWc22xZxw1sUHH0"
}.{
  "aud": "https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com",
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/{TENANT_ID}",
 ...
  "roles": [
    "Automation.ReadWrite.All",
    "app_access",
    "AdminCenter.ReadWrite.All",
    "API.ReadWrite.All"
  ],
...

  "ver": "1.0"
}.[Signature]


Do you want to call Dynamics 365 Business Central API or your own custom API?

Create App roles and grant API permissions for those app roles and generate access token.

Its my own custom api

Did you create App roles? and decode the access token in jwt.ms and check if role claim contains the required permissions

Added parts of the decoded token.

Can you also attach the screenshot of Expose an API blade?

Dont think we added anything in "Expose an api" (have a hard time checking now since the client dont let me login by myself without sharing screen and telling them where to click). Could it be there that we should expose the custom api?

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The error usually occurs if you are not adding the Microsoft Entra ID application in Dynamics 365 Business Central Portal and granting the permissions in the D365 Portal.
I created a Microsoft Entra ID application and granted API permissions:

Now, login to Dynamics 365 Business Central Portal -> Click on search icon -> Search Microsoft Entra Applications -> New


Paste the Microsoft Entra Application ClientID and set state as Enabled-> Click on YES


In the permissions tab give full access permission:

Now, login to Dynamics 365 Business Central Portal -> Settings -> Admin Center

And copy the TenantID and Environment Name:

I generated access token by using below parameters:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/.default


I am able to get the companies successfully like below:
GET https://api.businesscentral.dynamics.com/v2.0/TenantID/EnvironmentName/api/v2.0/companies


